# RKHunter gave me heaps of warnings

Tags: rkhunter

I ran a rkhunter search and i got these...

```
[09:59:13] System checks summary
[09:59:13] =====================
[09:59:13]
[09:59:13] File properties checks...
[09:59:13] Files checked: 149
[09:59:13] Suspect files: 1
[09:59:13]
[09:59:13] Rootkit checks...
[09:59:13] Rootkits checked : 479
[09:59:13] Possible rootkits: 9
[09:59:13]
[09:59:13] Applications checks...
[09:59:13] All checks skipped
[09:59:13]
[09:59:13] The system checks took: 1 minute and 48 seconds
[09:59:13]
[09:59:13] Info: End date is Wed May  1 09:59:13 BST 2019
(END)
 .
```

I tried to look at log ( had to look it up how ) and for example one of the warnings is this....

```
[09:58:56] Info: Starting test name 'passwd_changes'
[09:58:56]   Checking for passwd file changes                [ Warning ]
[09:58:56] Warning: User 'postfix' has been added to the passwd file.
```

Can someone please help me get rid of these or tell me whats wrong?

I started this because i suspect theres some rootkit in my system....

Thanks

I am on ubunty 18.04 btw

Comment: You would have a user `postfix` in the passwd file if you have installed the Postfix package. What is the output of `apt policy postfix`?

Comment: Hello @Jos thanks for replying. ..   postfix:
  Installed: 3.3.0-1ubuntu0.2
  Candidate: 3.3.0-1ubuntu0.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.3.0-1ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.3.0-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

Comment: So yes, you installed Postfix. Then it's obvious that you would have a `postfix` user. If you hadn't installed Postfix, having a `postfix` entry in the passwd file could point to malicious intent. Now it's a false positive.

Comment: Not sure whats postfix. I dont remember ever doing it... I have other errors too. cn you please have a look at all of them? and pease tell me where to find and upload the file. thank you very much ....

Comment: No, I won't go through a lot of similar warnings one by one. The procedure will be the same in every case and will give you lots of experience. If you don't know what you installed Postfix for, you may want to look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see what you were doing at the time when Postfix was installed. If you can't remember, then uninstall the package.

Comment: What is postfix for? also. how do i look at /var folder. i looked around and never found it

Comment: Come on. You can easily google [What is postfix for?](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+postfix+for) and [Linux directory structure](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+directory+structure). Both will give you excellent answers.

Comment: @Jos thanks, Heres my question. the reason i started looking it up at rkhunter is becase i have a server which i conenct through RDP, and i get the error saying someone else conencted and it force discinencts me,  it all started last night when i downloaded some files on my windows server. so my question is... could that be relative to this postfix? also is my ubuntu safe?  thank you very much for your time

Comment: That seems a bit far-fetched, but I can't completely exclude it. Please ask a new question with the contents of this last comment, including the exact error message. Also look at the output of `last` to see if anyone actually did log in.

Comment: Where do i put last?

Comment: It is a command. Open a terminal, type `last` and press Enter.

Comment: In ubuntu or My windows VPS?

Comment: wtmp begins Wed May  1 09:00:01 2019
On   ubuntu......